# Geodatabase to Style

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, arcgis-10.5

I have a geodatabase with 3 layers of symbology (marker, lines and polys), I need to convert these layers to styles in ArcGIS.

Comment: Are you asking how to save as a .lyr-file? Right click layer in table of contents - Save As Layer File

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all your layer in a map document, then symbolise all of them.

After that just use the "Export map style" command (you may need to manually add this command by going to Customize>Customize Mode then click the Commands tab, then select the Tools Category and finally find and drag the "export map style" to a toolbar)

Clicking this command will create a new style file that you can save anywhere and share with other, this file will contain all the style present in your document.

Comment: I did  Export mapstyle, it generates a style but it is empty.

Comment: I don´t want a lyr file, I need to generate a style to use by other users.